# All inserted rows in whole database in a time period in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database of 10 tables in MySQL.

I want to count/see the number of rows inserted into my 10 tables of whole database  in last one hour.

I know, I can do this keeping the inserted time in a column(**Created time**) of all tables.

But I want to know whether it is possible from MySQL information schema or not.

Comment: An easy one: It's not.

Comment: Why would be of the DB concern when you insert a row into a table? If it is important, it should be YOU who takes care of keeping this information.

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: You can add triggers to the table and track in a separate table, I believe